# How to get current url in views.py django?

Tags: python, django, url, view

First I read many answers here and mostly are about getting url in `template`.

I need to get url in `views.py` then I need to assign it as veriable.

I have 6 views like that and I have 6 querysets as well.

> SweatbandsView, HeadbandsView, BandanasView, BalloonsView ,TableCoversView, CoastersView

I created new view which is called Preview:

```
class Preview(SweatbandsView, HeadbandsView, BandanasView, BalloonsView ,TableCoversView, CoastersView):
          template_name = "preview.html"
```

As you see there, this view includes all of those. 
Now I need to get my current url and assign it like `the_url`.

Then Preview.py should be like this:

```
class Preview(SweatbandsView, HeadbandsView, BandanasView, BalloonsView ,TableCoversView, CoastersView):
     template_name = "preview.html"
     the_url = whatever_func_is_it()
     if (the_url == '/someting/something'):
         queryset = Product.objects.all().filter(category_id='6')
     else:
        .
        .
        .
        .
```

With this way I want to use needed queryset in if condition!

By the way I have 2 models in database which are Product and Category and they have OneToMany relation.

Thanks!

Comment: `request.META.get("HTTP_REFERER")`

Comment: It doesn’t make sense to inherit multiple views like `Preview(SweatbandsView, ...)`. Also, you can’t put that if statement in the class definition - that code runs when the module is loaded, before any requests have been received.

Comment: Thanks for answers. @Alasdair thanks again I didn't know it :)